# How can I pass output from command as list of arguments to a script?

Tags: bash, scripting, ls, arguments

I want to add content to a beginning of each file in current directory. I need to learn how to take all file names from current working directory at once and put them as arguments; I don't need to do this by specifying every file manually as an argument to the script. I want to use this new knowledge for further scripts. I don't need sideways or different solutions. I need to learn how to take command ( `ls` ) output and put it as an argument. I tried and failed to do that with:

```
./file-edit.sh $(ls)
./file-edit.sh `ls`
```

This is my script which works:

```
#!/bin/bash
lineno=2            # Append from line 2 
BAD_ARGS=85         # Error code

string0="###################################################################"
string2="#Description    :"
string3="#Date           :`date +%d-%B-%Y`"
string4="#Author         :Milos Stojanovic"
string5="#Contact:       :https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxx/"
string6="###################################################################"
# Can be any other strings

if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
        echo "Please specify at least 1 filename as an argument!"
        exit $BAD_ARGS
fi

until [ -z  "$1" ]
do
        string1="#Script Name    :$1"
        file=$1;
        sed -i ""$lineno"i $string0\n$string1\n$string2\n$string3\n$string4\n$string5\n$string6" $file
        echo "File "\'$file\'" altered at line number: $lineno"
        shift 1
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the other answers don't address what specifically you did wrong,

> I tried and failed to do that with:
>
> ```
> ./file-edit.sh $(ls)
> ```

I tried your script and I got:

```
$ ./file-edit.sh $(ls)
Please specify at least 1 filename as an argument!
```

On checking the output of `ls`, I noticed that it lists directories first. If I moved to a directory without subdirectories, I got:

```
$ ./file-edit.sh $(ls)
File 'a' altered at line number: 2
File 'b' altered at line number: 2
File 'c' altered at line number: 2
```

So, the way you're checking your arguments is the problem. `-f` only succeeds on regular files. It saw a directory was provided for the first argument and gave an error saying that the user didn't provide any filename arguments, even when they did.

If you want to make sure that at least one argument was provided, use `$#` which expands to the number of arguments provided:

```
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Please specify at least 1 filename as an argument!"
  ...
```

If you want to make sure they're regular files, then do the check in the loop, and check each one, not just the first.

```
until [ -z  "$1" ]
do
        string1="#Script Name    :$1"
        file=$1;
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
                sed -i "${lineno}i $string0\n$string1\n$string2\n$string3\n$string4\n$string5\n$string6" "$file"
                echo "File '$file' altered at line number: $lineno"
        fi
        shift 1
done
```

Now, that code is in case you want to ignore non-regular-file arguments, but you can just as easily change it to quit on seeing a non-regular-file if that's what you want.

That being said, it's not advised to use the output of `ls` like that. There can be filenames with spaces and bash will just split everything on whitespace. If you have a file `foo bar.txt`, bash will split that and your script will look for files `foo` and `bar.txt`.

From your comment on your question, I see someone must've suggested you use a glob instead. I don't really understand your point about it not working. `./file-edit.sh *` works just fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

To process each argument separately in your script, use a loop in your like so:

```sh
for pathname do

    # Insert code here that uses "$pathname".
    # You will not need to shift arguments.

done
```

To call your script with all the names in the current directory, use

```
./script.sh ./*
```

The shell will expand the `./*` pattern to a list containing all names in the current directory.

This has the advantage over using `ls` that it does not use `ls` and will therefore cope with filenames that contains any valid characters, even spaces, tabs and newlines.

Or, you can move the filename globbing into the script itself (to avoid having to give the script any arguments on the command line) with

```sh
for pathname in ./*; do
    # Insert code here that uses "$pathname".
done
```

If your script needs to distinguish between names that refer to regular files and names that refer to anything that is not a regular file (e.g. directories), use the `-f` test in your loop:

```sh
# skip non-regular files
[ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue
```

This would still let though symbolic links to regular files.  To skip these too, change the test into

```sh
if [ ! -f "$pathname" ] || [ -L "$pathname" ]; then
    # Skip non-regular files and symbolic links.
    continue
fi
```

---

Other comments:

You can assign a multi-line string to a variable by including newlines in the string:

```sh
boilerplate='Hello and welcome!
This is my program.
Enjoy'
```

To insert a text after line two in a text document using `sed` (using `-i` here for in-place editing):

```
printf '%s\n' "$boilerplate" | sed -i '2r /dev/stdin' somefile
```

or, with a here-document,

```
sed -i '2r /dev/stdin' somefile <<END_BOILERPLATE
Hello and welcome!
This is my program.
Enjoy
END_BOILERPLATE
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it now!

Answer (score 2):

I would have gone with something like:

```bsh
find <dir> -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '...'
```

instead of the whole `until` loop. Should be faster a bunch too.

The reasons I posted an alternative:

- [Thou shall not parseth `ls` output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) (600+ votes)
- I'd rather have one fast line in my script, using system mechanisms, than hack my own (possibly buggy) multi-line loop construct.
- Most self-built constructs will have problem with either "files with spaces", or run into problems with argument length.

Comment: Hello, thank you for suggestion. But i m not looking for some other way to do this. They are for sure many other solutions how else this could be done. Why i posted this question is because I want to learn, how to pass an output from a command as an argument to a script. Thank you!

Comment: @MilošStojanović proposing an alternative using `-print0 | xargs` was to help prevent yourself from shooting yourself in the foot later. But O.K., i also had to shoot myself in the foot once before i stopped parsing ls output myself, and looked up `xargs`usage..

Comment: Will test it with xargs also, thank you @AlexStragies

Comment: @MilošStojanović Solutions without `xargs` will fail in folders with either many files, and/or very long names (= "problems with argument length"). Fun to debug ... not!